# metafor: Including data in forest plot but not meta-analysis model

Tags: r, r-forestplot, metafor

I'm conducting a meta-analysis and would like to include a study in the forest plot, but exclude it from the meta-analytic estimate of the effect size. That is, I want to include that study for comparison purposes, but do not want it to contribute to the actual meta-analysis.

This is an odd case in which we have ~30 studies that used identical protocols. They are all direct replications of an original study. I want to include the original study in the forest plot for comparison purposes, but do not want to include it in the meta-analysis of the ~30 new studies. I saw that it's possible to deal with missing data (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472001/excluding-missing-variables-in-forest-plots-in-meta), but I don't see any way to specify rows of data to exclude from the model itself if I want to include them in the forest plot. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It takes a bit more manual work, but you can first create the forest plot with the `forest()` function (showing all studies and leaving some space for the summary estimate at the bottom), then fit the model (for example, with the `rma()` function) excluding whatever studies you do not want to part of the analysis, and then add the summary estimate with the `addpoly()` function.

Here is an example:

```
library(metafor)

### load BCG vaccine data
data(dat.bcg)

### calculate log relative risks and corresponding sampling variances
dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg, slab=paste(dat$author, dat$year, sep=","))
dat

### forest plot of all studies
forest(dat$yi, dat$vi, xlim=c(-9.5, 7.5), ylim=c(-1.5,16), atransf=exp, at=log(c(.05, .25, 1, 4, 20)))
text(-9.5, 15, "Author(s) and Year",    pos=4)
text( 7.5, 15, "Observed RR [95% CI]",  pos=2)

### random-effects model (without Aronson, 1948)
res <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat, subset=author!="Aronson")
res

### add summary estimate to the bottom
addpoly(res, atransf=exp, row=-1, mlab="RE Model (w/out Aronson, 1948)")

### horizontal separation line
abline(h=0)
```

Comment: That'll work. Thanks Wolfgang! I came up with basically the same thing this afternoon (before seeing your response, unfortunately). A bit clunky, but it does the job.

Comment: Like I said, a bit more manual work. Not sure I would call this 'clunky' though, since this is the entire point of the ``addpoly()`` function (to add summary polygons to forest plots). See ``help(addpoly)`` for more examples.